# Add attribute to anchor in AEM Rich text editor Link

Tags: aem, rich-text-editor

I am working on making one of the AEM website of my client accessible. For the same, I want "aria-label" attribute should be added(value can be provided in authoring dialogue) to the anchor tag, when the target selected is "New tab".
Could not find much around it, following link describes we can customize the rtePlugin/linkPicker. But could not figure out my problem. Any help/guidance

http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2017/06/aem-63-touch-ui-rte-rich-text-editor-color-picker-plugin-inplace-dialog-edit.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? Indeed, most likely you will have to create/overwrite the default link plugin.

Comment: @ronnyfm - This is the first project I am doing for AEM and could not find much option online for my requirement. So I have not tried anything as of now and looking for guidance here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1) Reuse `Alt Text`/title from otb anchor link. No need to customize dialog. When `Alt Text` is authored otb will populate title like this `<a title="Google" href="htttps://www.google.com">Google Link</a>`

[image],

You will then need to Write a [Link Transformer](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem63_link_rewriter.html) to copy title into aria-label. The rewriter will look for anchor tags; if title is present, copy into a new attribute aria-label and rewrite the anchor. If link rewriter is difficult, you can also rewrite the rte text from a sling model while saving the RTE text. Use a [Jsoup parser](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/html-parser-service.html) to parse HTML, rewrite by copying title to aria-label and write back into JCR.

Option 2) Adding new text box for aria-label to dialog. You can refer to this [blog post](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2017/09/aem-63-touch-ui-extend-rich-text-link-dialog-add-rel-select.html). But this option is needed only when `Alt text` is different from aria-label which I wonder why. Usually aria-label and titles are same and option 1 above will suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I was able to add the aria-label following 
http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2017/06/aem-63-touch-ui-rte-rich-text-editor-color-picker-plugin-inplace-dialog-edit.html

Another thing that I want is I want this to be added only when target="New Tab"
Any suggestion?

Comment: @Pradeep, http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2017/09/aem-63-touch-ui-extend-rich-text-link-dialog-add-rel-select.html - this blog closely matches your requirement than the color picker example. If you can reimplement similar to above example, you can add conditions in dlgToModel() function. It is called before dialog writes into JCR, so save aria-label to JCR only when condition satisfied. Another way is using LinkTransformer to remove attribute when not desired.

Answer (score 0):

So Finally was able to add aria-label attribute with some troubleshooting. Moreover the steps in the links mentioned above are same. Want to add additional details which I faced issue with

1. Adding new field
   Follow the steps mentioned in the [blog](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2017/09/aem-63-touch-ui-extend-rich-text-link-dialog-add-rel-select.html)
2. After adding the field as mentioned in the blog the newly added attribute will get filtered by AEM. You will see the following error in error.log file

   **Error** : "26.09.2017 12:40:42.804 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1506447642680] GET /content/we-retail/language-masters/en.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.xss.impl.HtmlToHtmlContentContext AntiSamy warning: The a tag contained an attribute that we could not process. The rel attribute had a value of "bookmark". This value could not be accepted for security reasons. We have chosen to remove this attribute from the tag and leave everything else in place so that we could process the input."

   **Solution**: Declare the attribute in the AntiSamy configuration file in CRXDE Light.
   **Note** : ma*ke the following changes in /apps/cq/xssprotection/config.xml (overlaying /libs/cq/xssprotection/config.xml), for Sightly/HTL its /libs/sling/xss/config.xml*
3. Copy /libs/cq/xssprotection/config.xml to /apps/cq/xssprotection/config.xml.
4. Open /apps/cq/xssprotection/config.xml.
   In the common-attributes section, add the following target attribute declaration.

   `<attribute name="aria-label>
       <regexp-list>
           <regexp value="[a-zA-Z0-9-_\$]+" />
       </regexp-list>
   </attribute>`
5. Find the tag declaration by searching the term `<tag name="a"`.
6. Add the line below in the list of attributes:

   `<attribute name="aria-label" />`

Save the file. Now, the link will open in a new window if the option is selected.